# create one page pdf of a website

Tags: php, html, web-services

I am in trouble .
 I want to create a one page PDF that no page gap between pages .
 I tried several plugins ,ad-dons, scripts software's all of them shows many  pages. my actual need is to get whole pages in single PDF like some screen capture plugins or ad-dons

Answer (score 1):

[wkHtmlToPDF](http://madalgo.au.dk/~jakobt/wkhtmltoxdoc/wkhtmltopdf-0.9.9-doc.html) allows to use `--page-height` parameter

Answer (score 0):

Use fPdf plugin. It helps you to generate pdf files

http://fpdf.org/

Answer (score 0):

If you are a chrome user -

You can use `chrome extension` - [Save as PDF](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-pdf/kpdjmbiefanbdgnkcikhllpmjnnllbbc?hl=en)

Link - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/save-as-pdf/kpdjmbiefanbdgnkcikhllpmjnnllbbc?hl=en